# Two subunits connected by only one disulfide bridge: quaternary structure?

Tags: proteins, structural-biology, protein-binding

I've always simply assumed quaternary structure to be characterized by non-covalent interactions such as hydrogen bonding, van der Waals interactions and whatnot. However, if two distinct polypeptides were *only* connected by one covalent disulfide bridge, would this be considered as quaternary structure, assuming that non-covalent interactions between the subunits are either negligible or even repulsive?

In other words, **can a disulfide bridge, on its own, convey quaternary structure?**

On a side note, are there any notable examples of this type of interaction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of any examples of this but I would say no doubt, that's quarternary structure. Quarternary isn't so much defined by the kind of interaction but much more the fact that it's between different polypeptides; all lower-level structures are within one polypeptide. ([Wikipedia agrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein_quaternary_structure).)

Answer (score 2):

I've always just gone with the name hetereodimer but there isn't any technical reason why it isn't a quaternary structure. As for an example, I work with antibody fragments or FAbs and cys-diabodies which are exactly that, two distinct polypeptides that are connected by a disulfide bond linkage.

These do have a significant amount of non-covalent interactions. For something with less, maybe ricin?